# phpThumb shows me "usage" example even though I've supplied the correct input

Tags: php, thumbnails, phpthumb

[phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) is a PHP library that converts large images to image thumbnails and caches the result. It takes such a syntax: `http://domain.com/phpThumb.php?src=/images/image.jpg`

However in my web application I'm following a strict MVC architecture, so I changed the syntax to this: `http://domain.com/thumb/images%2Fimage.jpg/width/height`

However now the output image is now complaining

> Usage: /workspace/urs/index.php?src=/path/and/filename.jpg

Even though I've checked the $_GET dump and it reads:

```
array(1) {
  ["src"]=>
  string(42) "/workspace/urs/images/portfolio/shoopm.jpg"
}
```

This is the code that runs up to the error (in my web application):

```
// If getting a thumbnail
if($qa[0] == "thumb")
{
    if(!isset($qa[1]) || !isset($qa[2]) || !isset($qa[3]))
        die("Bad thumb request. Needs 3 parameters!");

    unset($_GET["q"]);
    $_GET["src"] = $qa[1];
    $_GET["w"] = $qa[2];
    $_GET["h"] = $qa[3];

    include("phpThumb/phpThumb.php");

    exit();
}
```

Now, what I'm fearing is that phpThumb checks the actual URL, and not just the $_GET parameters... It's hard to confirm since the source contains thousands and thousands of lines of code and I haven't a clue where to start.

Thanks for any helpful replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [reading some of the source](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/index.php?source=phpThumb.php), it looks like it tries to do it's own `PATH_INFO` parsing.  You can prevent this by either changing the `disable_pathinfo_parsing` config variable, or setting `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to null.

This may be important because the "Usage: ..." error happens *only* when the `src` attribute of the `$phpThumb` object is empty.  It populates this attribute by looking for it in `$_GET`, and it does some pretty serious `$_GET['src']` manipulation when it tries to process `PATH_INFO`.

In the alternative, you might want to try just using it's own native `PATH_INFO`-based URLs instead of your own, just to avoid the futzing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when working on a windows system.

My src paths had a mix of forward `/` and back `\` slashes in the so I was converting them all o PHP's `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant (a backslash in windows).

When I converted them all to a forward slash it just worked